# M to N mapping with hibernate with extra columns using anotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to create a M to N mapping, with anotations, for this tables:

```
Table Food : Columns: id, description, size, type
Table Ingredients: Columns: id, description, price
Table Food_Ingredients: Columns: food_id (FK), ingredient_id (FK), quantity
```

Classes:

```
class Food {

   /*mapped fields setter/getters*/ 

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinTable( name = "food_ingredient", 
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "food_id", nullable = false) }, 
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id", nullable = false) })
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

}

class Ingredients {/*mapped fields setter/getters*/}
```

So, how can I map those entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you going to represent the quantity in your model? You should create a new entity for FoodIngredients with this property(and links to both other tables) and map it using `@OneToMany` annotations in Food and Ingredients.

Edit: You can use http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/ for reference

Comment: That's the only way that I am aware of. Food_Ingredients is not a junction table since it contains some extra data in additon to foreign keys. You need to convey information about quantity somehow so you need a new entity to do that.

Comment: It worked. I will try to enhance the solution to get simple classes, but you solution worked well. Thanks a lot.